# How NodeJS process other requests when my current synchronous loop isn't finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Take a look at the snippet below.

```
async create() {
  ......
  const parsedJSON = await bfj.parse(fs.createReadStream(file.path));
  logger.info('Parsing complete! Items: ' + parsedJSON.length);

  // Iterating over large data
  for (let index = 0; index < parsedJSON.length; index++) {
    parsedJSON[index].report.organizationId = this.app.get('organizationId');
    await this.DatagramService.create(parsedJSON[index].report); // DB insertion
  }
}
```

When I hit a certain endpoint, this `create()` function gets executed. As you can see it has a **synchronous** `for` loop. From my knowledge about NodeJS ***event loop***, that `for` loop should block the ***event loop***. But, while the `create()` is processing, I can hit other endpoints and get response from it. Although the response isn't quick (850ms).

If `for` loop is a blocking operation then how is NodeJS processing other request.

**Additional request**, is there any way of knowing at which phase the ***event-loop*** is currently in?

Comment: The for loop won't do any blocking unless you implement some kind of blocking mechanism.  True the for loop will be a synchronous call but there is nothing stopping any of the functions it processes in the loop from performing asynchronously.

Comment: `while(true)` is an event-loop-blocking operation. `await` is not

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek But, for loop is blocking operation.

Comment: @SPlatten Let's assume nodejs is currently processing my for loop. How, would it process another request since it is single threaded? https://nodejs.org/ru/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/#don-t-block-the-event-loop

Comment: `await` is stopping the code execution in the current task. But the `.DatagramService.create()` is an ordinary async operation. While JS is waiting for it to finish, it can handle other tasks from EL task queue. When the async operation finishes, it comes back to this particular task and continues executing the code. Think of it as a `Promise`, which obviously is non-blocking operation. `async/await` is just a syntactic sugar for `Promises` to make it easier to work with them and avoid callback hell

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I get your point. I literally didn't think it like that. Thank you.

Comment: @Dijkstra, the functions that node.js calls may reside in DLL's or Shared object libraries that are multi-threaded and any of the calls could result in a multi-threaded operation where the results are gathered in the background and then returned to the caller, these asynchronous operations can all be carried out without breaking the synchronous nature of the caller.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek wanna write down an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Dijkstra sure, posted as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, `await` is stopping the code execution in the current async function. The `.DatagramService.create()` is an ordinary async operation. While JS is waiting for it to finish, it can handle other tasks from the Event Loop task queue. When the async operation finishes, it comes back to this particular task and continues executing the code.

Think of it as a `Promise`, which obviously is non-blocking operation. `async/await` is just syntactic sugar for Promises to make it easier to work with them and avoid callback hell.

Answer (score 0):

How does the node js process other request? well you use **async await** on your function, it will not wait for the create() function to finish thus it will go to your other codes and process it, but once the create() function is finished it will notify the event loop and will produce the output of the function.

Answer (score 0):

fs.createReadStream is a async function. you try to write `await fs.createReadStream`. I think that it works

```
async create() {
  ......
  const parsedJSON = bfj.parse(await fs.createReadStream(file.path));
  logger.info('Parsing complete! Items: ' + parsedJSON.length);

  // Iterating over large data
  for (let index = 0; index < parsedJSON.length; index++) {
    parsedJSON[index].report.organizationId = this.app.get('organizationId');
    await this.DatagramService.create(parsedJSON[index].report); // DB insertion
  }
}
```